# me pueden ayudar estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio quiero sumar las columnas de la matriz para que me de un total de kilometros recorridos

Tags: array, c, algoritmos, bucles, operador

La empresa de transportes “The Big Old” cuenta con N choferes, de los cuales se conoce su nombre y los kilómetros que conducen durante cada día de la semana, esa información se guarda en un arreglo de N x 6. Se requiere un algoritmo que capture esa información y genere un vector con el total de kilómetros que recorrió cada chofer durante la semana.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  int main(){
  printf("Empresa de transportes Big Old\n\n");
  int n, i, x; // x,i contadores

  printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de choferes:\n");
  scanf("%i", &n);

 char nombres[n][30];

  int kilometros[n][6];
  char dias[6][20] = {"Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "viernes", "Sabado"};

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//filas
  {
      printf("\nIntroduzca el nombre del chofer: %d\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%s", nombres[i]);

      for (x = 0; x < 6; x++)//columnas
      {
          printf("\nIntroduzca la velocidad de kilometros a los que conduce:\n");
          scanf("%d", &kilometros[i][x]);
      }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//filas
  {
      int suma[i];
      suma[i] = 0;
      printf("\nConductor %d\n", i + 1);
      printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombres[i]);
      suma[i] += kilometros[i][x];
      for (x = 0; x < 6; x++)//columnas
      {
          printf("Dia: %s\n", dias[x]);
          printf("%d Km\n", kilometros[i][x]);
      }
      printf("El total de kilometros recorridos en la semana: %d\n\n", suma[i]);
  }


  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?